# I am not getting the Html which was in IFrame and generated by javascript

Tags: c#, selenium, web

**I am using selenium and Htmlaglity pack**
[here](http://www.galwaygaa.ie/index.php/en/football-fixtures-results2/football-fixtures) is website

And here is my Code

```
IWebDriver driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS.PhantomJSDriver("D:/Testing/");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(suburl);
Thread.Sleep(50000);
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000));
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(driver.PageSource);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch to the iframe before getting PageSource. See code below:

```
IWebDriver driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS.PhantomJSDriver("D:/Testing/");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(suburl);
Thread.Sleep(50000);
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000));
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(driver.PageSource);

driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("blockrandom")));
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument iframeDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
iframeDoc.LoadHtml(driver.PageSource);
```